# Слинковать CMake с еще не собранным таргетом

Tags: c++, cmake

Есть директория с компонентами, все из которых являются статическими библиотеками.
Они лежат в общей папке, каждая компонента имеет свой CMakeLists.txt и может собраться отдельно через CMake.

Также есть несколько утилит, каждая из которых может тянуть свои зависимости.

Пример иерархия папок:

```
[ git ]
- libraries
  - strings
  - my_math
  - media_converter
  - logger
- utilities
  - calc
  - video_player
```

Примеры CMakeLists.txt:

Для библиотеки:

```
project( library_name )
add_library( ${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC < .. > )
```

Для утилиты:

```
project( utility_name )
add_executable( ${PROJECT_NAME} < .. > )

  # import components :

add_subdirectory( <..> )           # компонента еще не собрана, собираем ее
target_include_directories( <..> ) # добавляю пути к заголовкам компоненты
target_link_libraries( <..> )      # линкуем к таргету 'utility_name' библиотеки компоненты
```

Таким образом, если одна из импортируемых компонент тянет что-нибудь еще, например, media_converter тянет за собой ffmpeg и когда я добавлю media_converter к video_player, то в CMakeLists.txt у video_player придется добавить конструкции типа "find_library( ffmpeg )", "target_link ..", чтобы разрешить все зависимости.

Вопрос в следующем. Как посредством CMake в скрипте для статической библиотеки указать утилите, которой ее использует, сразу подтягивать внешние зависимости компоненты?

Я попытался в CMakeLists.txt для компоненты использовать такую конструкцию:

```
project( library_name )
add_library( ${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC < .. > )
target_link_libraries( ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} < .. > )
```

По документации CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME - это название проекта для которого вызван CMake, т.е. в моем случае - это video_player. Но при таком раскладе у меня возникает ошибка - я пытаюсь слинковать компоненту с несуществующим таргетом.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? Пока не смог найти решение самостоятельно.

Comment: `target_link_libraries()` и `target_include_directories()` транзитивны. Если `video_player` зависит от `media_converter`, который зависит от `ffmpeg`, то `video_player` автоматически слинкуется с `ffmpeg` и будет видеть его заголовочные файлы (если `media_converter` _публично_ зависит от `ffmpeg`). Это не работает? Или я не до конца понял проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Структура**

```
├── libs
│   └── media_converter
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       └── main.cpp
└── utils
    └── video_player
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        └── main.cpp
```

**media_converter**

Сшздаём статическую библиотеку `media_converter`, находим и линкуем к ней зависимости. Обрати внимание, что зависимости публичные (PUBLIC).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(media_converter CXX)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC main.cpp)

find_library(MPG123_LIB mpg123)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${MPG123_LIB})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC /some/secret/path/to/mpg123)
```

**video_player**

Создаём приложение `video_player` и линкуемся с `media_converter`. Это автоматически добавит все публичные зависимости `media_converter` к `video_player`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(video_player CXX)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

add_subdirectory(../../libs/media_converter media_converter)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} media_converter)
```

**Проверка**

```
$ cmake ../utils/video_player/
...
Build files have been written to: .../build

$ make VERBOSE=1
...
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/video_player.dir/main.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -I/some/secret/path/to/mpg123   -o CMakeFiles/video_player.dir/main.cpp.o -c .../utils/video_player/main.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable video_player
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/video_player.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++     CMakeFiles/video_player.dir/main.cpp.o  -o video_player media_converter/libmedia_converter.a /usr/lib64/libmpg123.so
```

Как видно, `video_player` компилируется с `-I/some/secret/path/to/mpg123` и линкуется с `/usr/lib64/libmpg123.so`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, да, ошибка была в ключевом слове PUBLIC в target_link_libraries.